# AWS CloudFormation: Detect Drift

Tags: aws-cloudformation

While updating s3 bucket name through cloudformation, Its getting UPDATE_ROLL_BACK automatically and  Please let Is it possible to update S3 bucket name through cloudformation and how drift detecting works?.

Comment: Template used to create EC2 instance is :
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
 MyInstance:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
  Properties:
   AvailabilityZone: us-east-1a
   InstnaceType: t2.micro

Answer (score 0):

Updating bucket name requires a replacement. That means that CloudFormation will delete the bucket and then create a new one with the new name. CloudFormation won't delete buckets unless they're empty. That's probably why it fails for your case. To confirm this go to the CloudFormation console page, click on the stack and go to the events tab. Look at some of the latest events and one of them should be about failing to delete the bucket.

To get around this you need to empty your bucket before updating your stack. You probably want to backup all of its content, update the stack, and upload the content back to the new bucket.